# Follow Path constraint moves object away from curve?

Tags: camera, transforms, bezier-curves, constraints

I added a follow path constraint the camera.

I adjusted the start point of the path and the location of the camera so that they were very near, but once I set follow path constraint to the camera, it jumped to another location unintentionally.

So, although camera is following the path, there is some gap between the path and the camera.

According to a YouTube tutorial, this doesn't happen using the same steps.

Answer (score 12):

Positioning the camera to the starting point of the curve isn't necessary.

The camera's location defines an offset from it's constrained location. So to remove this offset, reset the camera's location to `0,0,0` by selecting the camera and pressing <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.

As an example of how this works, the camera is positioned at the start of the curve (2 BU above the world center):

[image]

When the constraint is defined, the camera is now 2 BU above the start of the curve, instead of the world center:

[image]

This is because the camera location is now relative to a point along the curve defined by the constraint, in this case the beginning.

Comment: Now I understand, original location of camera become offset camera location from path.

Comment: @blender_begginer Exactly :D If your question has been satisfactorily answered, consider marking an answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark under the vote icons :)

Comment: I have the same problem trying to follow a nurbPath with a sphere, they both have a 0,0,0 location, but the followpath modifer keep pushing the sphere away once it's applied :/

Comment: Just find out, i did apply the dimension with ctrl+A and it messed up the alt+G reset then... I gotta learn how locations works in blender... :S